# Upgrading old Unity code to Unity 5

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The code to play animation on trigger button does not seem to work. I saw a video on Youtube and with a simple `animation.Play();` it worked on that video but yet, I couldn't get it to work on my computer. What did I do wrong or did unity change it? please help I cant find solution on the net. All the "solution not working either".

This is the error I got:

> Type `UnityEngine.Component` does not contain a definition for play
>   and no extension method `Play` of type `UnityEngine.component` could
>   be found

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class animationtrigger : MonoBehaviour {


    void Start()
    {

    }
    int speed = 10;
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("N"))
        {
            animation.Play("Cube|moving side");
            //transform.Translate(1 * Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * speed);
            //Animator anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
            //if (null != anim)
        //  {
        //      anim.Play("Cube|moving side");
        //  }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by does not work? Do you get any error? Explain the problem you are having.

Comment: i added the error i got into the question

Comment: Check my answer. Please include your error message next time if there is one. You are lookin for **#1**. Read the rest or you will end up asking similar question again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what did i do wrong or did unity change it?

Unity changed. I've seen [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41657423/unity-error-unityengine-component-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-velocity/41657539#41657539) questions for the past few weeks. Although I don't think they are duplicates but it would make sense to answer all these here for future questions.

The `animation` *variable* is defined under `Component` as a `public` variable which `MonoBehaviour` inherits from. Your code then inherits from `MonoBehaviour` and you have access to `animation`.

These are the complete list of variables from the `Component` class that are deprecated:

```
public Component animation { get; }
public Component audio { get; }
public Component camera { get; }
public Component collider { get; }
public Component collider2D { get; }
public Component constantForce { get; }
public Component guiElement { get; }
public Component guiText { get; }
public Component guiTexture { get; }
public Component hingeJoint { get; }
public Component light { get; }
public Component networkView { get; }
public Component particleEmitter { get; 
public Component particleSystem { get; }
public Component renderer { get; }
public Component rigidbody { get; }
public Component rigidbody2D { get; }
```

**New way to access component that attached to the-same script**:

Use `GetComponent<ComponentName>()`. Capitalize the *first* letter of that variable to make it its component class. One exception is audio which becomes 
`AudioSource` instead of Audio.

**1**.`animation.Play("Cube|moving side");` becomes `GetComponent<Animation>().Play("Cube|moving side");`

**2**.`rigidbody2D.velocity` becomes `GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity`

**3**.`rigidbody.velocity` becomes  `GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity`

**4**.`renderer.material` becomes `GetComponent<Renderer>().material`

**5**.`particleSystem.Play()` becomes `GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().Play()`

**6**.`collider2D.bounds` becomes `GetComponent<Collider2D>().bounds`

**7**.`collider.bounds` becomes `GetComponent<Collider>().bounds`

**8**.`audio.Play("shoot");` becomes `GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play("shoot");`

**9**.`camera.depth` becomes `GetComponent<Camera>().depth`

I don't have to put all of them because the example below should  guide anyone do this. These are the most asked and asked components on SO.

**Cache Component**:

You can cache component so that you don't have be GetComponent everytime.

```
Animation myAnimation;
void Start()
{
    //Cache animation component
    myAnimation = GetComponent<Animation>();
}

void Update()
{
    if(somethingHappens)
    {
        //No GetComponent call required again
        myAnimation.Play("Cube|moving side");
    }
}
```

Comment: after i change the code monodevelop does not give an error from the code anymore but unity still couldnt find the animation for some reason even if i already uploaded it.

Comment: Make sure that the animation is check as "Legacy" because `Animation` component is a legacy stuff. Check [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/577801/animation-must-be-marked-as-legacy.html) post for the full possible solution for your new problem.

Comment: nvm i found the answer just need to make adjusment (theobject)->Rig (tab) -> change animation type to LEGACY

Comment: lol. we type it almost at the same time. Thank you for everything Programmer. your help is much appriciated :)

Answer (score -1):

If you're using an animator and you want to play a specific state, then you can do:

```
animator.Play("stateName");
```

I see that in the commented code below. That should be working. If nothing is happening then make sure that the "Cube|moving side" is a STATE name and not the ANIMATION name. Also make sure that the state actually contains an animation, and that the animation actually has frame data.

(Below, I have 2 states (Move and Idle). The state name is "Move" while the animation name is "test".)
[image]

If I wanted to switch to the move state, I would call ***animator.Play("Move")***.

Also I wouldn't recommend explicitally playing states. If you can manage it's generally better to make a state tree and trigger animations using parameters. You see in the image above how I have two states and transitions between them. You can assign parameters that can make my animator switch from one to another.

[image]

Here I use the "Example Anim Trigger" to make the animator switch from the Idle to Move state. I could do this in code with:

```
animator.SetTrigger("ExampleAnimTrigger");
```

This is the more modern way of using Unity animations, so I'd highly recommend picking this up.

[Here's the documentation!](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-AnimatorController.html)