# Unity3D AudioSource not being attached to Object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio-source

So hey. I have an Audio Source component attached to my object. I also copied the script from [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.PlayOneShot.html) and attached it to my object.

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;

 [RequireComponent(typeof(AudioSource))]
 public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
 {
     public AudioClip impact;
     AudioSource audio;

     void Start()
     {
         audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
     }

     public void play_sound()
     {
         audio.PlayOneShot(impact, 0.7F);
     }
 }
```

but when I try to use audio in my script I get it cut
[image]

what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inhering from `MonoBehaviour` which inherits from `Behaviour` and then from `Component` which has some variables declared in them such as:

```
public Component animation { get; }
public Component audio { get; }
public Component camera { get; }
public Component collider { get; }
public Component collider2D { get; }
public Component constantForce { get; }
public Component guiElement { get; }
public Component guiText { get; }
public Component guiTexture { get; }
public Component hingeJoint { get; }
public Component light { get; }
public Component networkView { get; }
public Component particleEmitter { get; 
public Component particleSystem { get; }
public Component renderer { get; }
public Component rigidbody { get; }
public Component rigidbody2D { get; }
```

**These are all deprecated** and no longer allowed to be used in the latest version of Unity. I believe it was deprecated from Unity 5 upwards. The document you linked is not yet updated. For more information see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41785057/upgrading-old-unity-code-to-unity-5/41786506#41786506) post.

All you have to do is rename your audio variable to something else and everything should work fine.

```
public AudioClip impact;
AudioSource myAudio;

void Start()
{
    myAudio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
}

public void play_sound()
{
    myAudio.PlayOneShot(impact, 0.7F);
}
```