# "new Camera camera" What does the term do in Unity3d?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was browsing through a camera script and came across the declaration term

```
new Camera camera;
```

I would like to know what this do. Is it creating a instance? What confused me this one is script is already attached to Camera Object in Inspector. So why is it necessary to create a instance of camera? It is defined above the class but not assigned to any variable. So what exactly it does in Unity3d?

Any particular use case for the above declaration?

Comment: Are you able to show us the **entire** contents of the file?

Comment: Is it creating a instance? YES What for?? Without the code we don't know

Comment: Nope, it's just a declaration overriding a base definition. It's not creating a new instance.

Comment: @mjwills The declaration is like that only. I understood now how this works. Programmer has given a very good explanation about overriding a base definition. It seems it is part of base classes which Unity's monobehviour is inheriting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This feature is called ["new Modifier"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-modifier).

You need to understand what's going on with the `camera` variable in Unity:

There is variable name "`camera`" declared in [`Component`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.html). When your script derive from [`MonoBehaviour`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html) which derives from [`Behaviour`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Behaviour.html) which finally derives from `Component`, you will inherit this `camera` variable. The `camera` variable let's you access the [`Camera`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.html) component that is attached to this GameObject this script is attache to.

The problem is that the `camera` variable is now deprecated and Unity now wants you to use `GetComponent<Camera>()` to get the `Camera` component attached to this GameObject. Even though it it deprecated, it is still there. It has not been removed. It is simply marked as deprecatedd with the `Obsolete` attribute.  You cannot declare variable with the name "`camera`".

For example, you can't do this:

```
Camera camera;
```

If you do, you will get the following warning which is annoying:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Warning   CS0108  'ScriptName.camera' hides inherited member
>   'Component.camera'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.

By using the `new` keyword to declare a variable named `camera`:

```
new Camera camera;
```

it will  hide the property of the base class and also remove that annoying warning

Comment: Or, you could use a different variable name!

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Yup. I was just explaining why `new ` is used in front of the codes he downloaded from online.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Yes I have used different variable name and tried with Getcomponent<Camera>() which resulted in same output. Just I was curios as why they used it. I actually pretty much forgot about that there are predefined Variable declarations coming in from Base component classes which resulted in this confusion. 
Programmer Thanks a lot. I understood now how this works. :)

Comment: You're welcome and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41785057/upgrading-old-unity-code-to-unity-5/41786506#41786506) is the list of the complete deprecated variable for those without Unity in front of them.

Comment: @Programmer so one question which pops up in my mind is what were the original intention of creating this variable components. Inheritance brings the variables of parents class so what benefits does this components earlier used to give? Were they able to give `instance.component` where component is one of the types and would it return them when we called like that if it exist on that object?

Comment: the original intention of creating them was to simplify retriveing built in componeys. For example, instead of doing  `Getcomponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce()` each time you want to add force to the Rigidbody2D attached to this GameObject, you would instead do `rigidbody2D.AddForce()` which is shorter but the issue with this is that people abuse this by using it in the `Update` function because it is slow to do that. By forcing people use `Getcomponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce()`, it will force users cache component to global variable and improve Unity games performance.

Comment: @Programmer I see. Thanks. I now understand why they did this :)